# Set select box value from array

Tags: php

I have this UI:
[image]

Also, I have this PHP Back-end code:

```
<select name="as<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>[]" style="width:250px;">

    <?php

        foreach ($product['uniSku'] as $key => $value) {
                echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                }
    ?>
</select>
```

The question is, how can i put the data SKU from array into the select box?

Comment: In the `foreach` loop try this - `echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['sku'].'</option>';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate twice in your multidimesional array

```
foreach ($product['uniSku'] as $data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $val) {
        echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$val.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Or if you need to use keys from your parent array you can store it in a variable at first iteration

```
foreach ($product['uniSku'] as $kk => $data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $val) {
        echo '<option value="'.$kk.'">'.$val.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fabio given the array structure by the OP, don't u think two iterations are overkill?

Comment: @sm1979 yes this definitly takes higher resource but will work in any condition, even if the array is different

Comment: @Fabio yes, I agree that it's more generic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution

```
foreach ($product['uniSku'] as $key => $value) {
      echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['sku'].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Replace `values` with `$value['sku']`

```
foreach ($product['uniSku'] as $key => $value) {
                echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['sku'].'</option>';
                }
```